# How do I get a combined result against a DB table using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a object structure like below.

```
    public class Response
    {
       public Security[] SecurityList{get;set;}
    }
    public class Security
    {
      public string Symbol{get;set;}
      public AssetClass[] AssetClassList{get;set;}
    }
    public class AssetClass
    {
      public string class{get;set;}
    }
```

Based on above structure the data can be in this xml format.

```
    <Response>
     <SecurityList>
       <Security>
         <Symbol>IBM</Symbol>
         <AssetClassList>
           <AssetClass>
                <class>AAA</class>
           </AssetClass> 
           <AssetClass>
                <class>BBB</class>
           </AssetClass>  
          </AssetClassList>
        </Security>
        <Security>
         <Symbol>HP</Symbol>
         <AssetClassList>
           <AssetClass>
                <class>CCC</class>
           </AssetClass> 
           <AssetClass>
                <class>DDD</class>
           </AssetClass> 
        </Security>
      </SecurityList>
    </Response>
```

I have a DB table which is having  common asset classes kind of reference data and i need to pull all the data for each security.

This is table structure:

```
    AssetClass  Classified  Othercolumns
    AAA          Y          XYZ
    BBB          N          XYZ
    CCC          N          XYZ
    DDD          N          XYZ
```

I need to get two different result set using LINQ.

```
    Result 1-
    Symbol AssetClass  Classified Othercolumnsdata 
    IBM    AAA         Y          XYZ
    IBM    BBB         N          XYZ
    HP     CCC         N          XYZ
    HP     DDD         N          XYZ
```

Currently I am using for-each loop and then Linq between asset classes   and table and combining all results together for each security.Have a feeling that there should be better way to do this
??

Result 2-For any security if even one asset class is classified as "Y" it will be considered as classified.

```
    Symbol      IsClassified
    IBM          Y
    HP           N
```

Thank you !!

Comment: From a T-SQL standpoint this is just `SELECT Symbol, MAX(IsClassified) FROM Table GROUP BY Symbol`. Perhaps you could write something similar in LINQ

Comment: Thx nick. I am looking for LINQ query not T-SQL.